# Dynamic Text in HTML5 Video

Tags: css, flash, html, overlay, html5-video

I would like to add text dynamically to HTML5 video.  Currently, this is achieved with Flash and passing in variables that Flash is expecting at certain time intervals.  What would be the equivalent (if any) in HTML5?  Does anyone have any examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this...

http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/accessible-html5-video-with-javascripted-captions/

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach: http://blog.app-solut.com/2011/03/display-additional-overlay-elements-on-top-of-an-html5-video-element-with-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

You could render the frames to a canvas, and then add the text from there. Here is an example 
http://www.craftymind.com/2010/04/20/blowing-up-html5-video-and-mapping-it-into-3d-space/

http://www.craftymind.com/factory/html5video/CanvasVideo.html

http://www.craftymind.com/factory/html5video/CanvasVideo3D.html

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent for this would be the text track api or the track element. Which gives you multiple things. A cuechange event for scripting (kind=metadata), using the text track api to directly render subtitles into the video (kind=subtitles).

As explained above, HTML5 gives you a DOMScripting and a Markup-API to achieve this. Currently only Safari supports this. You can find an [example using a polyfill here](http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/QZJTM/).